# PHP Wordpress sidebar doesn't show

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress magazine theme. Homepage it's a magazine, not a blog. In "Apperance" I have theme control panel named "theme options". In this panel I have sub-menu "Blog" and there I have to select exist wordpress page, which would be a blog. I created a blog page with name "blog" and default template. When I select page "blog" in theme control panel and open like this mydomain.com/index.php/blog there no have posts, only right sidebar witch search, categories and last posts. When I change template "default template" with "Blog" and open again url with browser show me blog posts, but right sidebar it's gone. This is blog-template.php

```
<?php
 /*
  Template Name: Blog
*/
 ?>
<?php get_header();?>

<section id="page-heading">
<div class="row">

  <div class="six columns">
    <div class="page-title">
      <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="six columns">
      <div class="search-box">
        <form id="search" action="<?php echo home_url();?>" method="get" >
          <input type="text" value="search..." onblur="if (this.value == ''){this.value = 'search...'; }" onfocus="if (this.value == 'search...') {this.value = ''; }" class="input-search" id="s" name="s" />
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>  
</section>
</div>
 <section id="page-bar">
 <div class="row">

   <div class="twelve columns">
     <div class="breadcrumbs">
       <?php if ( function_exists( 'breadcrumbs_plus' ) ) breadcrumbs_plus(); ?>
     </div>
   </div>     

  </div>  
</section>

 <div class="clear"></div>


 <div class="content">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="nine columns">

    <div class="main-content">
      <?php

      $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ?get_query_var('paged') : ((get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1);
      $blog_items_num = ($data['blog_item_number']) ? $data['blog_item_number'] : 3;
      $blog_order = ($data['blog_order']) ? $data['blog_order']  : "date"; 

      query_posts(array('post_type'=> 'post','posts_per_page'=>$blog_items_num,'orderby'=>$blog_order,'paged'=>$paged));
      while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      $thumb   = get_post_thumbnail_id();
      $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
      $image   = aq_resize( $img_url, 220,244, true ); //resize & crop the image
      ?>

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="blog-post <?php post_class(); ?>">                   
            <div class="post-thumb">
            <?php if ($image) { ?>                  
                <img src="<?php echo $image;?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>" class="img-border" />
            <?php } ?> 

            </div>                  
            <div class="post-content">
              <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h3>
              <?php the_excerpt();?>
              <div class="post-meta">                   
                <?php if ($data['disable_metapost'] == 0) { ?> 
                <span class="date"><?php the_time( get_option('date_format') ); ?></span>
                <span class="author"><?php the_author_posts_link();?></span>
                <span class="comment"><?php comments_popup_link(__('0 Comment','dream'),__('1 Comment','dream'),__('% Comments','dream'));?></span>
                <span class="category"><?php the_category(',');?></span>
                <?php } ?>
              </div>                                               
            </div>
        </div>

      <?php endwhile;wp_reset_query();?>

      <!-- begin of pagination -->
        <div class="blog-pagination">
            <!-- Pagination -->
           <?php pagination();?>  
           <!-- Pagination End -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of pagination --> 

    </div>

  </div>

  <?php get_sidebar();?>


  <div class="clear"></div>

   </div>

 <?php get_footer();?>
```

Sidebar name is `General Sidebar`

Comment: in the theme options is there a sidebar option to show/hide it?

Comment: No, just in pages, but when I set template blog and general sidebar, show me only blog.